# Pragmatically Convert a time to another times zone time

Tags: magento-1.7, date, timezone

I am trying to do something like:

My instance Locale default Timezone zone is  `Taipei Standard Time (Asia/Taipei)`
For a particular case,I want to get  my current time in `Tokyo Standard Time (Asia/Tokyo) time`.
How can i do this?Please help.

Suppose $order->getCreatedAt() give order creation time.

I would like something like:

```
$CurrentimeTaipeAsia=$order->getCreatedAt();
$currenttimeinTokyo=Mytimeconvert($order->getCreatedAt());
```

$currenttimeinTokyo give order create time in Tokyo time .

Comment: Thanks.. Kayur..But your solution is not works.I was give you upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using `DateTimeZone`

```
$date = new DateTime('7:10pm', new DateTimeZone('America/Montreal'));

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

just pass your timezone

which returns

```
2013-06-14 01:10:00+02:00
```

Read more about PHP and timezones here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php